# Sublime Not to Open Files in New Windows/Instances

Tags: windows, file, sublimetext2

When i open files from o/s File Browser, how can i make Sublime to open in same/existing windows instance? Not to open in separated instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `"open_files_in_new_window": false,` in .. "Settings - Default" file.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the default settings since they'll be overwritten when ST is upgraded. Using Settings..User is more appropriate